# KeyboardEvent isn't firing after interacting with svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a page with `svg` elements using which I drag-and-drop `rectangle`s and connect them to each other. You basically drag `li` elements and drop them on `svg`.

The problem is I cannot edit the input elements. I think the reason is interaction with `svg`, because I placed a dumb `input`. If you do not play with `svg`, you are able to edit input as usual. However, after drag-drop operation, then you cannot change the input.

What might be the problem?

**UPDATE** After investigating the problem a little more, I found out that `KeyboardEvent` isn't fired after drag-drop-and-draw operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that while interacting with `svg`, I prevent more `KeyboardEvent` to be dispatched by using `preventDefault` method. I had a method that deletes `SvgElement` when user selects it by clicking and then hits backspace. I thought preventing default behavior of backspace is required, apparently it is not.